# Settings lost on reboot

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I have a Dell XPS 15z which uses a Cypress TrackPad. It's running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.  Every time the laptop turns on, I have to go into the settings to turn off 'tap to click'. The setting remains for as long as the laptop is on, but is lost on a reboot. How can I force this setting to remain? Drivers are the latest ones downloaded a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled drivers, problem solved. Must try harder.